# CSS - float:left on a div not taking out of flow

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs:

```css
    div.main-info {
     background: yellow;
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
    }

    div.main-cta {
     background: red;
     width: 20px;
    }
```

```html
        <div id="wrapper">
         <div class="main-info">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
          <p>
           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
         </div>
         <div class="main-cta">
          <div class="window-cta">
           <p>Compare Now!</p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

but the `div` with class `main-cta` seems to be still at the 2nd line? Why is that? I thought that when you float a div, it will pop out of the doc's flow and the next element will occupy the first row where the floated element was and get hidden by it?

I'm kinda confused.

Thanks!

Comment: post your html too plz so we can try to solve at best.

Comment: `position: absolute` will take it out of the flow, not a `float`

Comment: can you back this up? all the articles states that float element will be out of the doc's flow.

Comment: If you will give float to an element then only his behavior/flow will change but not all the siblings elements. For this you have to change their flow too by applying float:left or right and it will be in same line. also you can use display:flex or inline block for sec div to take in same line.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this

<style>
div.main-info {
    background: yellow;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

div.main-cta {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly working. But I thought when you float an element, it will be out of the doc's flow? I don't want my `main-cta` class to be floated tho..

Answer (score 2):

I think it will help for you..

```css
div.main-info {
    background: yellow;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
div.main-cta {
    background: red;
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="wrapper">
            <div class="main-info">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </p>

            <div class="main-cta">
                <div class="window-cta">
                    <p>Compare Now!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `float:left` to `div.main-cta` .

```
div.main-info {
    background: yellow;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
div.main-cta {
    background: red;
    width: 20px;
    float: left; /*new line*/
}
```

Demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/f6stjstk/

Or you dont like to add `float:left` , you can use `display:inline-block;`

```
div.main-info {
    background: yellow;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block; /*new line*/
}
div.main-cta {
    background: red;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block; /*new line*/
    vertical-align: top; 
}
```

Demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/f6stjstk/2/

Answer (score 0):

In order to pop the `div` out of the flow, you need to make the `position` of the `div` absolute.

`float` asks the `div` to move toward the `left`, in the same row.

Comment: but won't get out of the flow?